# сбор массива из данных приходящих из бд

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Нужно собрать один массив из данных пользователя, которые записаны в несколько разных таблиц, в некоторых таблицах есть несколько записей относящихся к одному и тому же пользователю. Во всех таблицах есть общее поле `contid` которое хранит в себе `id` пользователей. Проблема в том, что получается вытащить либо массив, в котором данные либо не все(то есть только один телефон, только один майл, вместо нескольких записанных), либо выводится ошибка. В метод в модель приходит переменная, которая содержит нужный `id` пользователя, нужно по нему вытянуть данные.

```
public function getContactData($data)
{
    $this->db
         ->join('contacts_emails', 'contacts.contid = contacts_emails.contid', 'left')
         ->join('contacts_phones', 'contacts_emails.contid = contacts_phones.contid', 'left')
         ->join('contacts_names', 'contacts_phones.contid = contacts_names.contid', 'left');

    return $this->db
           ->get_where('contacts', array('contid' => $data['contid']))
           ->row_array();
}
```

при таком методе выдаёт ошибку `Column 'contid' in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: *выдаёт ошибку Column 'contid' in where clause is ambiguous* Каждому полю укажите алиас таблицы (т.е., скажем, не `contid`, a `contacts.contid`). Сервер должен понимать, из какой таблицы брать поле - ведь с таким именем есть поля в нескольких таблицах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `in where clause is ambiguous` говорит о том, что PostgreSQL не может определить колонку из какой нужно брать данные.

Сделаем минимально воспроизводимый пример:

Пускай есть две таблицы:

```
table1   | table2
id       | id
someName | someName
         | table1_fk
```

И есть следующий запрос:

```
SELECT someName 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_fk
```

И здесь мы получаем ошибку, т.к. колонка *someName* есть и в *table1* и в *table2*

Решение этой проблемы достаточно простое:

```
SELECT t1.someName --явно указываем из какой таблицы брать колонку
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_fk
```

Вам в Вашем случае необходимо будет *явно* указать таблицу, из которой Вы достаете данные.